# virsh, how to get full screen resolution via VNC

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virsh

I've got a few `KVM` VMs running on my home server, some of them running X.
I use `virsh` to manage them, and tunnel 5900x ports via SSH to access them via VNC.
I can't get the resolution to go higher than the default one, i've tried setting "vga" as the model type inside the video tag, the only thing that's changed is that now i can see higher resolutions in the XFCE monitor settings, but as soon as i set the one i need (1600x900) the screen goes numb (it's as hard to describe as to look at it), and i have to wait for the resolution to be reset.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: "vga" is wrong for most any modern operating system. You should be using "spice".

Comment: I am using vmvga now and it seems to work just fine